# jq: recursively merge objects and concatenate arrays

Tags: arrays, json, object, merge, jq

I have two json files, orig.json and patch.json, which have similar formats.

orig.json:

```
{
        "a": {
                "a1": "original a1",
                "a2": "original a2",
                "list": ["baz", "bar"]
        },
        "b": "original value B"
}
```

patch.json:

```
{
    "a": {
            "a1": "patch a1",
            "list": ["foo"]
    },
    "c": "original c"
}
```

Currently I am using `jq` to merge them recursively. However, jq's default behavior for lists is just reassignment. Example output from jq using `$ jq -s '.[0] * .[1]' orig.json patch.json`:

```
{
  "a": {
    "a1": "patch a1",
    "a2": "original a2",
    "list": [
      "foo"
    ]
  },
  "b": "original value B",
  "c": "original c"
}
```

Note that `a.list` is now equal to patch.json's `a.list`. I want The new `a.list` to be orig.json's list and patch.json's lists merged. In other words, I want `a.list` to equal `["baz", "bar", "foo"]`.

Is there a way I can easily do this with jq, perhaps by overriding the default merge strategy for arrays?

Answer (score 7):

Here is a generic function that recursively combines two composite JSON entities by concatenating arrays at the same position:

```
# Recursively meld a and b,
# concatenating arrays and
# favoring b when there is a conflict 
def meld(a; b):
  a as $a | b as $b
  | if ($a|type) == "object" and ($b|type) == "object"
    then reduce ([$a,$b]|add|keys_unsorted[]) as $k ({}; 
      .[$k] = meld( $a[$k]; $b[$k]) )
    elif ($a|type) == "array" and ($b|type) == "array"
    then $a+$b
    elif $b == null then $a
    else $b
    end;
```

### Output of meld($orig; $patch)

With $orig set to the contents of orig.json and
$patch set to the contents of patch.json:

```
{
  "a": {
    "a1": "patch a1",
    "a2": "original a2",
    "list": [
      "baz",
      "bar",
      "foo"
    ]
  },
  "b": "original value B",
  "c": "original c"
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to comment on edits directly: the `$` in the argument is more succinct and I believe easier to understand which is why I proposed it; if you want to use the `a as $a` construct I think it is tidier to do that just before the `reduce` to make it clearer that the value is being locked for a reason.

Comment: Using $ variables in the arguments of definitions is not supported in all extant versions of jq.  Defining the $-variables right up front is mainly done in the interests of efficiency and clarity.

Comment: Fair enough, I didn't realise $ arguments weren't available everywhere.  Thankyou for clarifying.

Comment: How do we use this function? Can you give an example command?

Comment: @KosProv: seems the way to run is `jq -f meld.jq 1.json 2.json ..` with the function definition in the file `meld.jq`, followed by the invocation statement needed (I used `reduce inputs as $i (.; meld(.; $i))`, to deep-merge several JSON files without slurping) ... careful about the **semicolon separating arguments**; a comma will give misleading error `meld/1 is not defined at <top-level>, line 16:`

Answer (score 7):

```sh
$ jq -s 'def deepmerge(a;b):
  reduce b[] as $item (a;
    reduce ($item | keys_unsorted[]) as $key (.;
      $item[$key] as $val | ($val | type) as $type | .[$key] = if ($type == "object") then
        deepmerge({}; [if .[$key] == null then {} else .[$key] end, $val])
      elif ($type == "array") then
        (.[$key] + $val | unique)
      else
        $val
      end)
    );
  deepmerge({}; .)' file1.json file2.json > merged.json
```

Answer (score 0):

The invocation:

```
jq -f patch.jq --argfile patch patch.json  orig.json
```

where patch.jq contains:

```
(.a.list + $patch.a.list) as $a
| . + $patch
| .a.list = $a
```

produces:

```
{
  "a": {
    "a1": "patch a1",
    "list": [
      "baz",
      "bar",
      "foo"
    ]
  },
  "b": "original value B",
  "c": "original c"
}
```