# jq merging multiple json files merging any array element

Tags: json, jq

I want to use jq to merge multiple files and if more than one file contains an array with the name, I need the arrays merged (order doesn't matter).

For example

file1

```
{
    "value1": 200,
    "timestamp": 1382461861,
    "parameter": [
    {"param": 1}
    ]
}
```

file2

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "timestamp": 1382461861,
    "value": {
        "aaa": {
            "value3": "v3",
            "value4": 4
        }
    },
    "parameter" [
    {"param": 2}
    ]
}
```

it is suggested other stack overflow articles to merge these json, I should do:

```
jq -s '.[0] * .[1]' file1 file2
```

yet this gets me:

```
{
  "value1": 200,
  "timestamp": 1382461861,
  "parameter": [
    {
      "param": 2
    }
  ],
  "status": 200,
  "value": {
    "aaa": {
      "value3": "v3",
      "value4": 4
    }
  }
}
```

where what I want is:

```
{
  "value1": 200,
  "timestamp": 1382461861,
  "parameter": [
    { "param": 1}, 
    { "param": 2}
  ],
  "status": 200,
  "value": {
    "aaa": {
      "value3": "v3",
      "value4": 4
    }
  }
}
```

notice the "parameter" array should have the elements from both file1 and file2

I also need a solution that doesn't require specifying the fields that array, and the arrays can be nested at any level of the json

I'm willing to accept a solution that is not using jq, a small python script would be ok I guess

the closest solution I have found requires me to know that parameter is an array

```
 jq -s '.[0] *  .[1]' file1.json file2.json >temp.json
 jq -s '.[0].parameter=([.[].parameter]|flatten)|.[0]' temp.json file1.json
```

and the output is

```
{
  "value1": 200,
  "timestamp": 1382461861,
  "parameter": [
    {
      "param": 2
    },
    {
      "param": 1
    }
  ],
  "status": 200,
  "value": {
    "aaa": {
      "value3": "v3",
      "value4": 4
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53661930/jq-recursively-merge-objects-and-concatenate-arrays similar

Comment: @AC - Please clarify the requirements, especially if there are more than two files.

Comment: So by "merging" an array, you mean to take the corresponding items and merge them?

Comment: just two files. I want the array elements appended to the array. I clarified that by editing my  example having the two elements in the arrays have the same keys.

Comment: So basically you want to have the semantics of what oguz ismail linked then? Concatenate the arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution to the problem in the case that there are two files, each with one object in which there is at least one same-named array-valued field at some level.

The requirements are unclear on many points, so the following may require tweaking in accordance with more detailed requirements.  If there are more than two files, then the same techniques can be used, but again the details will depend on the detailed requirements.

```
jq -n --slurpfile file1 file1.json --slurpfile file2 file2.json '

  # a and b are expected to be jq paths ending with a string
  # emit the array of the intersection of key names
  def common(a;b):
    ((a|map(.[-1])) + (b|map(.[-1]))) 
    | unique;

  $file1[0] as $f1
  | $file2[0] as $f2
  | [$f1 | paths as $p | select(getpath($p) | type == "array") | $p] as $p1
  | [$f2 | paths as $p | select(getpath($p) | type == "array") | $p] as $p2
  | $f1+$f2
  | if ($p1|length) > 0 and ($p2|length) > 0 
    then common($p1; $p2) as $both
    | if ($both|length) > 0 
      then first( $p1[] | select(.[-1] == $both[0])) as $p1
      |    first( $p2[] | select(.[-1] == $both[0])) as $p2
      | ($f1 | getpath($p1)) as $a1
      | ($f2 | getpath($p2)) as $a2
      | setpath($p1; $a1 + $a2)
      else .
      end
    else .
    end
  '
```

### Output

Using the given input, after adding the missing ":" in the second file, the output is:

```
{
  "value1": 200,
  "timestamp": 1382461861,
  "parameter": [
    {
      "param1": 1
    },
    {
      "param2": 2
    }
  ],
  "status": 200,
  "value": {
    "aaa": {
      "value3": "v3",
      "value4": 4
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're basically implementing your own merging scheme. If you want a generalized solution, you'll want to define a function so it could be done recursively. This won't be quite the same as "`*` but with different array semantics" but you could use something like this:

```
def new_merge($item):
    if type == ($item|type) then   # if same types
        if type == "array" then        # concatenate the arrays
            . + $item
        elif type == "object" then     # recursively merge objects
            reduce ($item|to_entries[]) as {$key,$value} (.;
                .[$key] |= new_merge($value)
            )
        else                           # just take the "other" value
            $item // .
        end
    else                           # just take the "other" value
        $item // .
    end
    ;
```

I'd put this in your `~/.jq` file and invoke like this:

```
$ jq 'reduce inputs as $i (.; do_merge($i))' file*.json
{
  "value1": 200,
  "timestamp": 1382461861,
  "parameter": [
    {
      "param": 1
    },
    {
      "param": 2
    }
  ],
  "status": 200,
  "value": {
    "aaa": {
      "value3": "v3",
      "value4": 4
    }
  }
}
```

If on the other hand you wanted array items recursively merged as you had it in your original question, just change the array case to recursively merge corresponding items.

```
def new_merge2($item):
    if type == ($item|type) then
        if type == "array" then
            [.,$item] | transpose[] as [$a,$b] | [$a | new_merge2($b)]
        elif type == "object" then
            reduce ($item|to_entries[]) as {$key,$value} (.;
                .[$key] |= new_merge2($value)
            )
        else
            $item // .
        end
    else
        $item // .
    end
    ;
```

This version would produce:

```
{
  "value1": 200,
  "timestamp": 1382461861,
  "parameter": [
    {
      "param1": 1,
      "param2": 2
    }
  ],
  "status": 200,
  "value": {
    "aaa": {
      "value3": "v3",
      "value4": 4
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple but generic solution to the problem in the case of two files, each with one object.

This solution will concatenate each pair of arrays at the same path.  Hopefully it is simple enough for it to speak for itself and for modifications to be made to handle a wide range of more detailed requirements.

```
jq -n --slurpfile file1 file1.json --slurpfile file2 file2.json '
  $file1[0] as $f1
  | $file2[0] as $f2
  | reduce ($f1 | paths) as $p ($f1+$f2;
      ($f1|getpath($p)) as $v1
      | ($f2|getpath($p)) as $v2
      | if ($v1 | type == "array") and
           ($v2 | type == "array")
        then setpath($p; $v1 + $v2)
        else .
        end)

'
```

The output is exactly as required, assuming that the second file has been corrected in the obvious way so that it is valid JSON.