# JQ push data from 1 file into nested array in another file

Tags: arrays, file, nested, addition, jq

I have 2 files:

**f1.json**

```
{
  "a.b": {
    "c": [ 1, 2 ]
  },
  "d": "other data"
}
```

**f2.json**

```
{
  "a.b": {
    "c": [ 3, 4 ]
  }
}
```

All details of the nested array in *f2.json* should be merged into *f1.json* as seen below

**f1.json:**

```
{
  "a.b": {
    "c": [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
  },
  "d": "other data"
}
```

Locating the array in **f1.json**:

```
jq -s '.[0]["a.b"].c f1.json
```

Accessing the array in **f2.json** (as this is going to be a static file, we don't need to rely on the specific name of a.b):

```
jq .[].c f2.json
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jq: recursively merge objects and concatenate arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53661930/jq-recursively-merge-objects-and-concatenate-arrays)

Comment: Use the `f2.json` as the reference in the `--argfile` and while processing the `f1.json` add the array contents together

    `jq --argfile sec f2.json '."a.b".c += $sec."a.b".c' f1.json`

Comment: @oguzismail How is the meld function invocated?

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to merge both arrays (and take all other property of `f1.json` as is):

```
jq -s '.[0]."a.b".c += .[1]."a.b".c | .[0]' f1.json f2.json
```

This will append array of f2 to the array of f1 and then select f1 only.

If your merging rules are more complex than outlined in your question, leave a comment and edit your question with clarification (and better example inputs).

---

Or with using `--slurpfile`:

```
jq --slurpfile f2 f2.json '."a.b".c += $f2[0]."a.b".c' f1.json
```

The idea is the same, but the input is only a single file, while the second file's content can be accessed via `$f2` in your filter.