# JQ - Recursive dedupe & concatenate JSON objects based on a uniquely identifying field

Tags: json, merge, jq

I'm trying to dedupe and merge multiple JSON objects together, based on an id field on every JSON object.

In the example below, the values of the "employee.id" and "hobbygroup.id" fields are used to determine whether to dedupe the duplicated value and remove it, or instead concatenate its separate value into another location that preserves the hierarchy.

For example:

```
{
   "employee":[
      {
         "employee.id":"11",
         "employee.name":"bob",
         "hobbygroup":{
            "hobbygroup.id":"1",
            "hobbygroup.name":"chess",
            "groupmeeting":{
               "groupmeeting.id":"a",
               "groupmeeting.name":"kickoff meeting"
            }
         }
      },
      { # new hobbygroup.id, so this hobbygroup gets concatenated with the hobbygroup "1" above
         "employee.id":"11",
         "employee.name":"bob",
         "hobbygroup":{
            "hobbygroup.id":"2",
            "hobbygroup.name":"boxing",
            "groupmeeting":{
               "groupmeeting.id":"a",
               "groupmeeting.name":"kickoff meeting"
            }
         }
      },
      { # same hobbygroup.id and employee.id as before, but new group meeting, gets concat with groupmeeting "a"
         "employee.id":"11",
         "employee.name":"bob",
         "hobbygroup":{
            "hobbygroup.id":"2",
            "hobbygroup.name":"boxing",
            "groupmeeting":{
               "groupmeeting.id":"b",
               "groupmeeting.name":"second meeting"
            }
         }
      },
      { # duplicate employee.id as well as hobbygroup.id, gets deduped/ignored
         "employee.id":"11",
         "employee.name":"bob",
         "hobbygroup":{
            "hobbygroup.id":"2",
            "hobbygroup.name":"boxing"
         }
      },
      { # new employee.id, gets concatenated with employee 11 into an array
         "employee.id":"12",
         "employee.name":"bill",
         "hobbygroup":{
            "hobbygroup.id":"1",
            "hobbygroup.name":"chess",
            "groupmeeting":{
               "groupmeeting.id":"a",
               "groupmeeting.name":"kickoff meeting"
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Should return:

```
{
   "employee":[
      {
         "employee.id":"11",
         "employee.name":"bob",
         "hobbygroup":[
            {
               "hobbygroup.id":"1",
               "hobbygroup.name":"chess",
               "groupmeeting":{
                  "groupmeeting.id":"a",
                  "groupmeeting.name":"kickoff meeting"
               }
            },
            {
               "hobbygroup.id":"2",
               "hobbygroup.name":"boxing",
               "groupmeeting":[
                  {
                     "groupmeeting.id":"a",
                     "groupmeeting.name":"kickoff meeting"
                  },
                  {
                     "groupmeeting.id":"b",
                     "groupmeeting.name":"second meeting"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "employee.id":"12",
         "employee.name":"bill",
         "hobbygroup":{
            "hobbygroup.id":"11",
            "hobbygroup.name":"chess",
            "groupmeeting":{
               "groupmeeting.id":"a",
               "groupmeeting.name":"kickoff meeting"
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

#### Example Explanation

At the first level, if the value of "employee.id" matches between the objects, then:

1. Any child fields in the object (employee.name) gets deduped/overwritten.
2. Any child objects (hobbygroup) get evaluated to see if its corresponding id field (hobbygroup.id) matches.

   - If matching, then steps 1 and 2 are reapplied recursively to this object. (ie, merge any fields, and then look at any children objects of hobbygroup)
   - If not matching, then these 2 hobbygroup objects get concatenated into an array of hobbygroups under the parent object (employee), as "hobbygroups": [{chess...}, {boxing...}]

#### Potential Inputs

- Input JSON objects can have an arbitrary number of nesting levels.
- Each of these objects have a field representing the dedupe key (employee.id & hobbygroup.id in this case). The input keys can all be preemptively renamed to something consistent to make it easier to access, such as "key.id".
- The solution needs to be generic since there's a recursive requirement; it shouldn't require knowing the names of the fields or how it's nested.

#### Current approach I'm trying

I've found a couple of threads for merging JSON objects such as [jq: recursively merge objects and concatenate arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53661930/jq-recursively-merge-objects-and-concatenate-arrays), which creates a function similar to the recursively merging multiply operation (*), except that it instead concatenates whenever it runs across an array.

I think a similar approach could work here, along with an additional conditional check against the id (only concatenating if the ids don't match). However, I'm new to JQ and it looks like there may be a few ways to get to the same result, so I might be missing a more simpler declarative solution.

Thanks!

Comment: The input and expected output as shown are not quite valid JSON, even after the # comments are removed.  Please fix.

Comment: If the recursion requirement is important, then it would be helpful to have an illustrative example.

Comment: Sorry about that! The extra commas were left accidentally when I removed extra nesting levels from the example to make it easier to read. I’ll add them back to resolve both issues. Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by recursion? Simply that the objects' details (here represented by a simple `.name`) can grow deeper and have to be merged recursively as well? Or that the `."employee.id"` and `.hobbygroup."hobbygroup.id"` constellation may appear on multiple levels, maybe even nested inside each other? Or more generically that any `."<group>.id"` and `.<subgroup>."<subgroup>.id"` constellation should be considerd?

Comment: The potential inputs here could be nested to a large degree, eg, an `Employee` could have a child `HobbyGroup`, which could have a child `GroupMeeting`, which could have a child `MeetingRoom`, etc. The deduping logic would have to apply to each of those levels, so I’m suspecting recursion is necessary in the resulting filter. In the updated example, the 1st and 3rd object have matching `employee.id` and `hobbygroup.id`, but a different `groupmeeting.id`, which should cause the `employee` and `hobbygroup` to merge, while the 2 different `groupmeeting` objects `a` and `b` will concatenate.

Comment: When calling your script, do you want to explicitly provide a list of names for these groups (here `employee`, `hobbygroup`, `groupmeeting`, etc.), or should they be detected automatically? If the latter, based on what criteria? Is it simply all objects that share a same field name `X`, under which there is a child object with a field named `X.id`? Is this parent-child relation always an object-object relation, and the array-object relation seen at top level (`employee`) is the only exception to that? How about intermediate levels between parent and child, or between child and the next parent?

Comment: Thanks for the clarifying Qs, they help me understand my own question better! For simplicity, the groups can be known in advance (as well as the id field names). The parent-child relation is always an object-object; I removed the top level one for brevity, but you make a good point in that it doesn't show consistency so I've added it back. Any fields on the parent that aren't objects are considered scalar fields owned by the parent, and follow the rule, "Any child fields in the object (employee.name) gets deduped/overwritten.", b/c if the id matches, those fields will always be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the clarifications. Still not sure about some edge cases, but this should cover most general cases. It detects parent-child relationships of one level distance if the child object has the same field name with `.id` added to it, and applies the merger recursively onto the first relationship found (except for the hard-coded top level as it is an array-object, not an object-object relationship). It also removes array brackets if only one child object is left.

```bash
def merge_by(f):
  group_by(f) | map(
    [paths[1:3] | select("\(first).id" == last)] as [$p]
    | if $p then first + {($p[0]): (
        map(getpath($p[:1])) | merge_by(getpath($p[1:]))
        | if length == 1 then first else . end
      )} else .[] end // empty
  );
  
.employee |= merge_by(."employee.id")
```

```json
{
  "employee": [
    {
      "employee.id": "11",
      "employee.name": "bob",
      "hobbygroup": [
        {
          "hobbygroup.id": "1",
          "hobbygroup.name": "chess",
          "groupmeeting": {
            "groupmeeting.id": "a",
            "groupmeeting.name": "kickoff meeting"
          }
        },
        {
          "hobbygroup.id": "2",
          "hobbygroup.name": "boxing",
          "groupmeeting": [
            {
              "groupmeeting.id": "a",
              "groupmeeting.name": "kickoff meeting"
            },
            {
              "groupmeeting.id": "b",
              "groupmeeting.name": "second meeting"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "employee.id": "12",
      "employee.name": "bill",
      "hobbygroup": {
        "hobbygroup.id": "1",
        "hobbygroup.name": "chess",
        "groupmeeting": {
          "groupmeeting.id": "a",
          "groupmeeting.name": "kickoff meeting"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/I5CJzpR7G7a)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the requirements, especially those regarding recursion, but the following
does produce the desired result for the given example (after trivial corrections), and does include a recursive
call to the "dedup" filter, so if it does not meet your requirements, hopefully
it will provide a suitable framework for a solution.

```
# input: an array
def coalesce(f):
  (map([f]) | add | unique) as $f
  | add
  | f = $f ;

def dedup:
  if type == "array" and length > 1
  then unique
  | if (.[0] | has("employee.id"))
    then group_by(.["employee.id"])
    | map( coalesce(.hobbygroup) )
      else .
      end
  else .
  end ;

def recursively(f):
  if type == "array" then f | map(recursively(f))
  else .
  end;

recursively( dedup )
```