# Using jq, how can I merge two (or more) objects with the same keys whose value is an array while concatenating the array?

Tags: json, merge, jq

Imagine we have two json objects:

`{"messages":["one"], "keyA": "valueA"}`

and

`{"messages":["two"], "keyB": "valueB"}`

I expect there's a way to merge these two objects while concatenating the array values, such that the resulting object would be:

`{"messages":["one","two"], "keyA": "valueA", "keyB": "valueB"}`

Most of the approaches I've seen thus far to do this are inadequate in that the array gets overwritten by the "right most" object's version.

i.e.:

`echo '{"messages":["one"], "keyA": "valueA"}{"messages":["two"], "keyB": "valueB"}' | jq -s '.[0] * .[1]'`

produces:

```
  "messages": [
    "two"
  ],
  "keyA": "valueA",
  "keyB": "valueB"
}
```

(NOTE: the `messages` array value only contains `two` (from the second (right-most) object)

From the [jq manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Builtinoperatorsandfunctions) on the "add" command:

> Objects are added by merging, that is, inserting all the key-value pairs from both objects into a single combined object. If both objects contain a value for the same key, the object on the right of the + wins. **(For recursive merge use the * operator.)**

(emphasis added)

But changing the `+` operator to `*` does not appear to change the output.

I've seen [jq: recursively merge objects and concatenate arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53661930/jq-recursively-merge-objects-and-concatenate-arrays) but... wow... is there no better way?

Bonus points if the solution can handle an object whose array key's value is `null` as if it were an empty array:

`{"messages":null, "keyA": "valueA"}{"messages":["two"], "keyB": "valueB"}`

Comment: For one level (as in your sample) you can obviously make it simpler (as the referenced solutions), but for a recursive merging that adheres to a specific paradigm, you need that overhead to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple approaches I found:

First, this is a [known issue](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/957)

Second, from the known issues I found this:

`jq -s '[.[] | to_entries] | flatten | reduce .[] as $dot ({}; .[$dot.key] += $dot.value)'`

e.g.:

`echo '{"messages":["one"], "keyA": "valueA"}{"messages":["two"], "keyB": "valueB"}' | jq -s '[.[] | to_entries] | flatten | reduce .[] as $dot ({}; .[$dot.key] += $dot.value)'`

produces:

```
{
  "messages": [
    "one",
    "two"
  ],
  "keyA": "valueA",
  "keyB": "valueB"
}
```

(as desired)

This is from https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/502

Additionally, inspired by https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/957 I was able to do this:

`echo '{"messages":["one"], "keyA": "valueA"}{"messages":["two"], "keyB": "valueB"}' | jq -s '.[2].messages = .[0].messages + .[1].messages | .[0] + .[1] + .[2]'`

Which also produces the expected output, but in a non-generalized way. The inspiration to store the desired merged array in the third element of the root array is pretty neat (which is why I mention it); then use the existing "right side wins" behavior to insert the properly merged array back into the result.

Lastly, from that same issue, there's this:

`echo '{"messages":["one"], "keyA": "valueA"}{"messages":["two"], "keyB": "valueB"}' | jq -s '.[0] as $o1 | .[1] as $o2 | ($o1 + $o2) | .messages = ($o1.messages + $o2.messages)'`

which is essentially the same non-generalized solution (but perhaps more elegant?) than the temp-storage approach above.

Comment: As [commented above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75596476/#comment133371613_75596476), this simple case (just one level, referencing the array by name, etc.) is strikingly simple (no need for `-s`, even: `… | jq 'input as $in | . + $in + {messages: (.messages + $in.messages)}'`). It's the recursive deep merge that is complicated (to encode) as all edge cases (type mismatch, null handling, etc.) need to be checked on each level. Also note that merging arrays by concatenation is not a "missing feature issue" because it's counter-intuitive, as it does not align, thus breaks recursability.

Answer (score 0):

For simple examples such as in the question, the following filter
provides a simple but principled approach that also qualifies for the “bonus points”:

```
# Assumption: the input and $obj are objects that are array-consistent
# in the sense that if $k is a key of either object, then:
# (a) if .[$k] is an array then $obj[$k] is an array or null, and
# (b) if $obj[$k] is an array, then .[$k] is an array or null
# The output is . + $obj except that array-valued keys are concatenated.
# WARNING: the assumption is not checked.
def combine($obj):
  . as $in
  | reduce ($obj|keys_unsorted[]) as $key
      ($in;
       if (.[$key] | type) == "array" then .[$key] += $obj[$key]
       else .[$key] = $obj[$key]
       end ) ;
```

Of course, this is not commutative.

For more than two objects, simply use `reduce`, e.g. for an array of objects:

```
def combine: if length==0 then . else reduce .[] as $_ ([]; combine($_)):
```